# Android how to measure Upload/Download speed wifi/2G/3G...?

Tags: android, file-upload, download

i have searched on Google but not found any tutorial to measure speed of android `wifi/2G/3G` network speed.

By searching lot finally got Download speed for [THIS](http://www.gregbugaj.com/?p=47) any one have idea of upload speed.

any one guide me is there any `API` or tutorial exists for this? any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement your own speedtest measurement routines. You can find the algorithm description of Ookla's speedtest here:
http://wiki.ookla.com/lq_test_flow

Basically what you have to do is to execute download and upload routines and measure the time of the download and upload. You can use *System.nanoTime()* for more accurate timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

A very straight forward general method requiring no special tools is:

Upload/Download a file of known size to some server (you can use dropbox etc if you don't have your own server) and measure the time taken using a [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html).

Then you can easily calculate the speeds using the collected data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in Android library because there are many sampling methodologies , there is no one "true" speed. You can check following standards to give you more idea what is the recommended way:

https://itu.int/en/ITU-T/C-I/Pages/IM/Internet-speed.aspx

https://itu.int/itu-t/recommendations/rec.aspx?rec=q.3960

https://itu.int/ITU-T/recommendations/rec.aspx?rec=14125

https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc6349.pdf

Whatever algorithm you pick, make sure its multithreaded (parallel download of a file(s) in multiple threads, the same for upload)

You can also use our Android SDK which should do what you need and is compliant with ITU standard:

https://github.com/speedchecker/speedchecker-sdk-android